# How do I Access to Embed Code in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have admin rights in Power BI and everything appears to be turned on correctly on my site, yet I'm still getting [Embed Code Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lyw9.png) when I try to get a code.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Tara Osborn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without access what settings you have/haven't enabled.

However, you definitely need to make sure 'Publish to web' is enabled:

1. In the top right corner, click the 3 dots next to your profile
2. Then hover over Settings
3. Then click Admin portal
4. Click 'Tenant settings'
5. Scroll down to 'Export and Sharing Settings' on the right part
6. Click the 'Publish to web' option.
7. The dropdown should open, make sure the 'Publish to web' option is enabled. Without this enabled, it won't work.
8. Click apply.

Comment: ah hah!  It was checked, but the "Allow new codes" was not.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @TYOzzy There you go! They never make it easy do they? :) You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following have been enabled in Power BI admin portal in order to be able to generate embed code to publish report to the web.

> Please note that the report and data is visible by anyone having links to the report when you're publishing report to the web.

1. Developer Settings

- Embed content in apps : Enabled

2. Export and sharing settings

- Publish to Web : Enabled
- Allow existing and new codes : Enabled

[image: Power BI Admin settings]